# runtime library and global namespace

Tags: c++

Does the runtime library pollute the global namespace?

Comment: I am referring to the runtime library as specified here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library

The runtime library is not the standard library, it is used to implement the exception handling, together with other things in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime library is required to use reserved identifiers. Without namespace qualification, these must begin with two underscores: `__start`, etc.

You are not allowed to use reserved names. The library is not allowed to use your names. If either crosses over to the other, it is "pollution" which is illegal.

Essentially, the situation is the same for C and C++ except, as the other answers point out, in C++ most *standard library* names have namespace qualification.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you really understand the terms you are using, but the names in the C++ Standard Library exist in the std namespace, so the answer is no. The names in the header files that originated in the C Standard Library are placed in the global namespace, if you #include them via the .h filenames, such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

if you #include them like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

then the names exist in both global and std namespaces.

The reason for placing objects in the std namespace is not so much to avoid "namespace polution", which is hardly  a value neutral term, but to avoid name clashes.

Comment: the runtime library does not seem to be inside the standard library.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library

Comment: @Curia Then please clarify what names you are asking about. The C++ Standard does not specify a runtime library. In C++ namespaces are compile-time objects and cannot be "poluted" by a runtime anything.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the library cleanly goes in namespace `std:` -- however, for backwards compatibility with `C`, you may choose to "pollute" the global namespace by including old headers like `<math.h>` (which puts lots of names in the global namespace) instead of the proper new ones like `<cmath>` (which uses the `std:` namespace properly).

Comment: Avtually, most implementations put the names in BOTH namespaces if you #include cmath et al.